"The server cannot be started because one or more of the ports are invalid. Open the server editor and correct the invalid ports". on Eclipse
I have installed Tomcat 9 (port 8081) and Tomcat 10 (port 8080) on my system, and have tested them to be running at installation.
I have then set up the runtime environment on my Eclipse for these servers and then when I try starting the server, i get the error:

The server cannot be started because one or more of the ports are invalid. Open the server editor and correct the invalid ports.

for both of them, I have checked in command prompt using netstat -ano | findstr :8080 and netstat -ano | findstr :8081
and I see these ports are not being used.
I also tried changing port to 8082, still the same issue.
I even tried restarting my pc, and the issue still persists.
to check, i even tried using startup.bat from bin folder of the tomcat, and then it is working, i can see at http://localhost:8081/
but not working in eclipse


Why do you have something other than a number specified for the admin port?
